# Galois action on units of totally real cyclic numberfields

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Given a cyclic totally real number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree n with unit group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$, how much is known about the action of Gal$(K/\mathbb{Q})$ on the generators of the free part of the unit group? I can assume $n$ is prime if that helps me say something.

Are there units $u$ for which we know how $u$ and $\sigma(u)$ are related multiplicatively where $\sigma$ is a generator of Gal$(K/\mathbb{Q})$? i.e. in terms of the generators of the unit group, do we sometimes know how to express the product or ratio of $u$ and $\sigma(u)$ or can we say anything about it?

Comment: Christine, the "free part" as a subgroup doesn't have a well-defined meaning since the product decomposition you wrote down is not canonical.  For example, $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{2}]^\times = \pm(1+\sqrt{2})^{\mathbf Z} = \pm(1 - \sqrt{2})^{\mathbf Z}$ and the subgroups generated by $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$ are unequal. Perhaps instead you want to look at the quotient group ${\mathcal O_K}^\times/\{\pm 1\}$, which is free, and the Galois action on that?

Comment: Of course the strict answer to your question is "yes" we know such a unit: try $u =1$.  It's pretty easy to describe how $u$ and $\sigma(u)$ are multiplicative related, but that silly choice isn't really what you're after.  I think what you might want to read about is Minkowski units.  Look up that term in the appendix to Washington's book on cyclotomic fields.

Comment: Looking around a bit, I see the term "Minkowski unit" might be used in two different ways.  Washington means it to be a unit whose Galois conjugates generate a subgroup of finite index in the unit group, while other sources I check use the term to mean a unit whose Galois conjugates generate the whole unit group modulo roots of unity. In the first sense it always exists and in the second sense it may not exist (there are restrictions).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Keith!